# How to Build a useful filterable list? (such as Amazon features in their left side bar)

Tags: filter, listbox, product

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of what I would need to learn to build a list such as the one at http://pointblankseo.com/link-building-strategies. I want to eventually be able to build something similar for a product list (where product characteristics are listed in an above header and the user checks/unchecks their desired characteristics and then below this header section the list of products with those specific characteristics are then shown.) Almost something like Amazon just a lot less complex. I'm pretty sure that some sort of back end programming and database knowledge is required here?

What would be the most efficient way to learn how to and build something like this? What programming language should be used?

I know this is a pretty broad question but just a little direction would be a huge help to me so I know where to get started and where to direct my energy in learning this process.